# Shiny app which Uploads a datafile and create a checkbox and textinput and dropdown list for each column

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

[Here is a video which explains what I want](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHy0I-4torM).

I want to upload a file and then for each column, a checkbox should appear.

If the checkbox is checked, then a dropdown list and two textinputs should be shown for each column.

If it's not checked, then the checkbox and two textinputs should disappear.

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnBYa.jpg) has only two text inputs and a dropdown for the first column but it should have two textinput and dropdown for each checkbox.

Check out the analysis tab after uploading a data file

UI code:

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage(title="Analysis",
             tabPanel(title="Input",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput("file","Upload the file"),
                          checkboxInput('file_has_headers',"Take Column Names from the first row of the file",value= TRUE),
                          checkboxInput('show_head_only',"Display only first 6 rows. Uncheck this to see entire file",value= TRUE),
                          radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
                          textAreaInput("domains", 'Enter the comma separated list of dimensions, for example: verbal ability, numerical ability' ),
                          width = 4
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          wellPanel(
                            DT::dataTableOutput("uploaded_table"
                            ),# Displays the uploaded table by using js dataTable from DT package
                          ),
                          width = 8
                        ),
                        position = 'left'
                      )      
             ), #End of Input Tab panel
             
             tabPanel(title="Verification",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(2,
                               "V",
                               uiOutput('choose_columns')
                        ),
                        column(2,
                               "Key",
                               textInput('anser_key',"",placeholder = 'e.g. A')
                        ),
                        column(4,
                               "Dimension",
                               uiOutput("domain_dropdown",inline = FALSE)
                        ),
                        column(3,
                               "Valid Options",
                               textInput('valid_options',"",placeholder = 'e.g. A,B,C,D')
                        ),
                      ) # End Fluid row    
             ), #End of Verification Tab Panel
             navbarMenu(title="Analayis",
                        tabPanel(title="Item Analysis", "content"
                                 
                        ), #End of Item Analysis Tab Panel
                        tabPanel(title="Test Analysis", "content"
                                 
                        ) #End of Test Analysis Tab Panel
             ) #End of navbarMenu
  ) #End of navbarPage
) #end of shinyUI
```

Server code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=300*1024^2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  #1: Get the uploaded file in the data variable 
  data <- reactive({
    uploaded <- input$file
    #if(is.null(file1)){return("No file is selected or selected file is not in the right format. Please check the documentation and upload correct file.")} 
    req(uploaded) #req retruns a silence rather than error and is better than using if()
    if(input$show_head_only){
      head(read.csv(file=uploaded$datapath, sep=input$sep,header = input$file_has_headers)) #head() returns only first 6 rows
    } else {
      read.csv(file=uploaded$datapath, sep=input$sep,header = input$file_has_headers) 
    }
  })
  
  #2:set the elemet for domain dropdown list.
  output$domain_dropdown <- renderUI({
    items <- strsplit(input$domains,',')[[1]] #It creates a list and [[1]] retuns the list as c('','') which is needed for select input
    selectInput(inputId = "domains", label = "", choices =  items)
  })
  
  
  #3: set element to show the uploaded csv file as a table
  output$uploaded_table<- DT::renderDataTable(
    data(), # If a variable contains the output of reactive() function, it must be used as a function.
    server=TRUE, #Important to keep this as true so that large datasets do not crash the browser
    options = list(
      scrollX = TRUE
    ),
  ) # End of uploaded table output setting
  
  #4: Set dynamic checkboxes based on the number of columns in the data
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    colnames <- names(data())
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       # selected = colnames
    )
  })
  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(title="Analysis",
             tabPanel(title="Input",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          fileInput("file","Upload the file"),
                          checkboxInput('file_has_headers',"Take Column Names from the first row of the file",value= TRUE),
                          checkboxInput('show_head_only',"Display only first 6 rows. Uncheck this to see entire file",value= TRUE),
                          radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ','),
                          textAreaInput("domains", 'Enter the comma seperated list of dimensions, for example: verbal ability, numerical ability' ),
                          width = 4
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          wellPanel(
                            DT::dataTableOutput("uploaded_table"
                            ),# Displays the uploaded table by using js dataTable from DT package
                          ),
                          width = 8
                        ),
                        position = 'left'
                      )      
             ), #End of Input Tab panel
             
             tabPanel(title="Verification",
                      
                      fillRow(flex = c(1,4),
                              fillCol(uiOutput('choose_columns')),
                              fillCol(fluidRow(column(8,uiOutput('kdv'))))
                              )  ## end of fillRow
                      
             ), #End of Verification Tab Panel
             navbarMenu(title="Analayis",
                        tabPanel(title="Item Analysis", "content"
                                 
                        ), #End of Item Analysis Tab Panel
                        tabPanel(title="Test Analysis", "content"
                                 
                        ) #End of Test Analysis Tab Panel
             ) #End of navbarMenu
  ) #End of navbarPage
) #end of shinyUI

library(shiny)
library(DT)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=300*1024^2)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  #1: Get the uploaded file in the data variable 
  data <- reactive({
    uploaded <- input$file
    #if(is.null(file1)){return("No file is selected or selected file is not in the right format. Please check the documentation and upload correct file.")} 
    req(uploaded) #req retruns a silence rather than error and is better than using if()
    if(input$show_head_only){
      head(read.csv(file=uploaded$datapath, sep=input$sep,header = input$file_has_headers)) #head() returns only first 6 rows
    } else {
      read.csv(file=uploaded$datapath, sep=input$sep,header = input$file_has_headers) 
    }
  })
  
  #2:set the element for domain dropdown list.
  output$domain_dropdown <- renderUI({
    req(input$columns)
    items <- strsplit(input$columns,',') # [[1]] #It creates a list and [[1]] returns the list as c('','') which is needed for select input
    selectInput(inputId = "domains", label = "", choices =  items)
  })
  
  
  #3: set element to show the uploaded csv file as a table
  output$uploaded_table<- DT::renderDataTable(
    data(), # If a variable contains the output of reactive() function, it must be used as a function.
    server=TRUE, #Important to keep this as true so that large datasets do not crash the browser
    options = list(
      scrollX = TRUE
    ),
  ) # End of uploaded table output setting
  
  #4: Set dynamic checkboxes based on the number of columns in the data
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    colnames <- names(data())
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       # selected = colnames
    )
  })
  
  output$kdv <- renderUI({
    n <- length(names(data()))
    colnames <- names(data())
    if (is.null(input$columns)){return(NULL)
    }else{
      tagList(
        lapply(1:n, function(i){
          lapply(input$columns , function(par){
            if (colnames[i]==par){
              div(
                div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; width: 145px ;",textInput(paste0('answer_key',i),"",placeholder = 'e.g. A')),
                div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; width: 155px ;",selectInput(paste0('sel_var',i), "", choices=data()[[par]])),
                div(style="display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; width: 145px ;",textInput(paste0('valid_options',i),"",placeholder = 'e.g. A,B,C,D'))
              )
            }
          })
        })
      )
    }
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I made a video here which explains what i want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHy0I-4torM

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what i wanted! thank you!

Comment: I am guessing that this is using HTML which i am not really aware of how it is used. I can see that we can change the width of these boxes. Is there any way to change the distance between the boxes and the height of the boxes?

Comment: I think I have answered your original question.  For changing the box size or giving space between checkboxes, you should do some research or ask a separate question.  It may require some CSS or JavaScript adjustment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! i will learn more on CSS first

Comment: If this answered your original question, please accept the answer. It is considered polite to accept an answer that has answered your OP. This helps others who are looking for a solution for the same/similar query. Furthermore, people may be willing to help you in your future queries.

Comment: I am so sorry! I am very new to coding and this website so i did not know how to do it. I will do it immediately